# Opening a protocol (112, vrrp) with Ubuntu 20.04 ufw to allow multicasting

Tags: ubuntu, ufw

I've been installing keepalived on my Ubuntu 20.04 box however for VRRP to work (using multicast) I need protocol 112 opened up on the firewall (note this is a protocol, not a port).

From everything I've seen, it doesn't seem to be possible with ufw however some research shows that I might be able to manually edit some files in the /etc/ufw directory to get the protocol added to the netfilter system.

I know I can make this work with the unicast_peer commands by ignoring the protocol and just opening up all IP from host to host. This isn't ideal of course, but gets around the multicast protocol issue.  However I have a couple places where I need multicasting (224.0.0.18, protocol 112) to work and hence this posting.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Marcos

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow incoming to multicast:

```
ufw allow in on eth0 from 192.168.1.0/24 to 224.0.0.18 comment 'keepalived multicast'
```

`192.168.1.0/24` is the source you are allowing from and the key is to `224.0.0.18` which is multicast.

More info [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-verify-keepalived-working-or-not/) which did not help (opening up 'ah' protocol did not work). Ultimately the comment [here](https://enotacoes.wordpress.com/2014/05/06/keepalived-ip-failover/) by KevP is what provided the solution for me.